# Bayesian Stackelberg game

Tags: probability, game-theory, conditional-probability, differential-games

Can anybody provide me a little example of bayesian stackelberg game with the solution.

I know how to solve Stackelberg game using backward induction but have no idea about bayesian.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer this question if you do not provide some context.

The label "Bayesian Stackelberg games" has been used around 2008 in a small set of papers; for a simple example, [see p. 2 here](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/2008/AAAI08-262.pdf).